# Matlab Camera Calibration - Correct lens distortion

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab, matlab-cvst

In the Computer Vision System Toolbox for Matlab there are three types of interpolation methods used for [Correct lens distortion](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/releases/R2013b/vision/ref/undistortimage.html).

Interpolation method for the function to use on the input image. The interp input interpolation method can be the string, 'nearest', 'linear', or 'cubic'.

My question is: what is the difference between 'nearest', 'linear', or 'cubic' ? and which one implemented in "Zhang" and "Heikkila, J, and O. Silven" methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation method is actually independent of the camera calibration. Any time you apply a geometric transformation to an image, such as rotation, re-sizing, or distortion compensation, the pixels in the new image will correspond to points between the pixels of the old image.  So you have to interpolate their values somehow.

'nearest' means you simply use the value of the nearest pixel.
'linear'  means you use bi-linear interpolation. The new pixel's value is a weighted sum of the values of the neighboring pixels in the input image, where the weights are proportional to distances.
'cubic'   means you use a bi-cubic interpolation, which is more complicated than bi-linear, but may give you a smoother image.

A good description of these interpolation methods is given in the documentation for the [interp2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) function.

And finally, just to clarify, the `undistortImage` function is in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I can't access the paged at the link you wrote in your question (it asks for a username and password) and so I assume your linked page has the same contents of the page http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/vision/ref/undistortimage.html which I quote here:

> `J = undistortImage(I,cameraParameters,interp)` removes lens distortion from the input image, `I` and specifies the
>   interpolation method for the function to use on the input image.
>
> Input Arguments
>
> `I` — Input image
>
> `cameraParameters` — Object for storing camera parameters
>
> `interp` — Interpolation method
>
> `'linear'` (default) | `'nearest'` | `'cubic'`
>
> Interpolation method for the function to use on
>   the input image. The interp input interpolation method can be the
>   string, `'nearest'`, `'linear'`, or `'cubic'`.

Furthermore, I assume you are referring to these papers:

ZHANG, Zhengyou. A flexible new technique for camera calibration. *Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, IEEE Transactions on*, 2000, 22.11: 1330-1334.

HEIKKILA, Janne; SILVEN, Olli. A four-step camera calibration procedure with implicit image correction. In: *Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 1997. Proceedings., 1997 IEEE Computer Society Conference on*. IEEE, 1997. p. 1106-1112.

I have searched for the word "interpolation" in the two pdf documents [Zhang](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.145.7481&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Heikkila and Silven](http://www.npl.illinois.edu/ftp/nathan/Motion%20Capture/heikkila97.pdf) and I did not find any direct statement about the interpolation method they have used.

To my knowledge, in general, a camera calibration method is concerned on how to estimate the intrinsic, extrinsic and lens distortion parameters (all these parameters are inside the input argument `cameraParameters` of Matlab's `undistortImage` function); the interpolation method is part of a different problem, i.e. the problem of "Geometric Image Transformations".

I quote from the [OpenCV's page Geometric Image Transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) (I have slightly modified the original omitting some details and adding some definitions, I assume you are working with grey level image):

> The functions in this section perform various geometrical
>   transformations of 2D images. They do not change the image content but
>   deform the pixel grid and map this deformed grid to the destination
>   image. In fact, to avoid sampling artifacts, the mapping is done in
>   the reverse order, from destination to the source. That is, for each
>   pixel (x, y) of the destination image, the functions compute
>   coordinates of the corresponding “donor” pixel in the source image and
>   copy the pixel value:
>
> `dst(x,y) = src(f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y))`
>
> where
>
> `dst(x,y)` is the grey value of the pixel located at row `x` and column `y` in the destination image
>
> `src(x,y)` is the grey value of the pixel located at row `x` and column `y` in the source image
>
> `f_x` is a function that maps the row `x` and the column `y` to a new row, it just uses coordinates and not the grey level.
>
> `f_y` is a function that maps the row `x` and the column `y` to a new column, it just uses coordinates and not the grey level.
>
> The actual implementations of the geometrical transformations, from
>   the most generic remap() and to the simplest and the fastest resize()
>   , need to solve two main problems with the above formula:
>
> • Extrapolation of non-existing pixels. Similarly to the filtering
>   functions described in the previous section, for some `(x,y)` , either
>   one of `f_x(x,y)` , or `f_y(x,y)` , or both of them may fall outside of
>   the image. In this case, an extrapolation method needs to be used.
>   OpenCV provides the same selection of extrapolation methods as in the
>   filtering functions. In addition, it provides the method
>   BORDER_TRANSPARENT . This means that the corresponding pixels in the
>   destination image will not be modified at all.
>
> • Interpolation of pixel
>   values. Usually `f_x(x,y)` and `f_y(x,y)` are floating-point numbers. This
>   means that `<f_x, f_y>` can be either an affine or
>   perspective transformation, or **radial lens distortion correction**, and
>   so on. So, a pixel value at fractional coordinates needs to be
>   retrieved. In the simplest case, the coordinates can be just rounded
>   to the nearest integer coordinates and the corresponding pixel can be
>   used. This is called a nearest-neighbor interpolation. However, a
>   better result can be achieved by using more sophisticated
>   interpolation methods, where a polynomial function is fit into some
>   neighborhood of the computed pixel `(f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y))`, and then the
>   value of the polynomial at `(f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y))` is taken as the
>   interpolated pixel value. In OpenCV, you can choose between several
>   interpolation methods. See resize() for details.

For a "soft" introduction see also for example [Cambridge in colour - DIGITAL IMAGE INTERPOLATION](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm).

So let's say you need the grey level of pixel at x=20.2 y=14.7, since x and y are number with a fractional part different from zero you will need to "invent" (compute) the grey level in some way. In the simplest case (`'nearest'` interpolation) you just say that the grey level at (20.2,14.7) is the grey level you retrieve at (20,15), it is called "nearest" because 20 is the nearest integer value to 20.2 and 15 is the nearest integer value to 14.7.

In the (bi)`'linear'` interpolation you will compute the value at (20.2,14.7) with a combination of the grey levels of the four pixels at (20,14), (20,15), (21,14), (21,15); for the details on how to compute the combination see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) which has [a numeric example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Application_in_image_processing).

The (bi)`'cubic'` interpolation considers the combination of sixteen pixels in order to compute the value at (20.2,14.7), see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation).

I suggest you to try all the three methods, with the same input image, and see the differences in the output image.